# What is the best way to label user-inputted arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, label, user-input

I am creating a word generator like [Awkwords](http://akana.conlang.org/tools/awkwords/) that randomly picks a letter from a labelled array and puts it in a sequence.

I am currently just having the label be the first item of its array. Here's a simple version:

```
let sequence = 'CVC'
let word = ''
let consonants = ['C', 'b', 'c', 'd',]
let vowels = ['V', 'a', 'e', 'i',]
let lists = [consonants, vowels]

for (letter of sequence) {
  for (list of lists) {
    if (list[0] === letter) {
      pick random letter out of the list other than its first value and add it to the word
    }
  }
}
```

I'm almost brand new to programming in general so I have no idea if this is the way I should be doing this. Is there a more efficient way to label an array?

There will be a max of 26 lists (one for each letter) and the items within them will change depending on what the user inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get something like a "labeled array" is to use a javascript object. Here you could use the letters as *keys* (or *properties*) and the associated list as the *value*. This would also save you looping through the lists to search for the desired letter.

Try something like below:

```js
let sequence = "CVC";
let word = "";
let patterns = {
  C: ["b", "c", "d"],
  V: ["a", "e", "i"]
};

for (letter of sequence) {
  // do something here with patterns[letter]
  console.log(patterns[letter])
}
```